# What's the complexity of this function?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I'm practising in Codeacademy and I have to make the following function:

Define a function called anti_vowel that takes one string, text, as input and returns the text with all of the vowels removed

This is my solution.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
md = ""
for ch in text:
    if ch not in "aeiouAEIOU":
        md =  md + ch
return md
```

It works well but I'm wondering what the complexity of the function is.

I think it's `O(nk)` where n:="length of text" and k:="length of "aeoiuAEIOU"".
 I take one element of text and compare it with all vowels, that takes O(k) time. But I repeat that n times, so I do it all in `O(nk)`. Is my analysis correct? How could I improve my function? Could it be linear?

Comment: Note that your indentation is incorrect as shown. I presume your actual code has it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the complexity of your function is `O(nk)`. What you missed is that `O(nk)` is equal to `O(n)` if `k` is a constant not equal to zero. That means your function already runs in linear time.

You are iterating over a string `text` with `n` characters.
Each iteration, you check whether the current character is in a string of *fixed* length `k` (`k` is a constant!). At worst, this check will take `k` steps.

Thus, your complexity is:

`O(k)O(n) = O(kn) = O(n)`

I suggest you read up on the basic properties of complexity classes, in particular how their sum, their product and multiplication by a constant work [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties).

Answer (score 7):

Big-O complexity doesn't work like that. `k` (the length of the vowels) is a constant, it doesn't change depending on the length of the input. So we discount it in calculating the complexity.

Your function is just O(n), ie linear complexity.